# Please clean up diskpart.com spam by user Metaphor

Tags: support, spam

User [Metaphor](https://superuser.com/users/1692216/metaphor) (1692216) is spamming diskpart ads. Can someone clean that up please?

Comment: Have you raised a custom "in need of moderator intervention" flag explaining the issue? That should be the first thing you do when you notice a problem like this.

Comment: @cigien Thanks, I did.

Comment: Someone suspended the account for 7 days, but the spam has not been cleaned up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close the loop

[image]

This was a case of boom tommorrow. Always boom tomorrow.

Comment: Boom. Sooner or later. BOOM!